# iOS Parse XML iTunes:image tag

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing, rss, podcast

I am trying to parse a podcast to build a table view of its contents in my app.  The picture for the podcast is in a tag listed as:

```
<itunes:image href="http://www.site.com/picture.jpg" />
```

In my app, I try to get the contents of the string using:

```
 NSString *articleImage = [item valueForChild:@"itunes:image"];
```

When I run a log for this string, nothing shows up.  So, how would I go about getting the URL of the jpg from this particular tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url is in an attribute called href, valueForChild gets the text value of the element, which is quite correctly empty.
You want to use `[item attributeForName:@"href"]` where `item` is your `itunes:image` element.